# Can't Understand Sentence Containing Word "Keep The Difference"

Tags: vocabulary, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I work for a client at the rate of X USD (United State Dollars) per hour. Recently, he accidentally paid me at the rate of Y USD per hour. Y is greater than X.

I notified him of his mistake and he replied with the following sentence:-

> Go ahead and keep the difference to be applied to the next round of work you do for us.

What does this mean? Should I accept the payment at the rate of Y USD per hour or correct it to X USD per hour?

Comment: Yes, it means "keep the extra as profit for this week, which I'll deduct from the next payment". But as Myron said, you should definitely clarify. ;)

Comment: It should be noted that using "keep the difference" in the above context is not quite idiomatic.  Ordinarily the phrase means that you should consider the "difference" between the offered payment and what you are owed as a "tip" (gift).  But in this case he apparently wants you to hold the excess amount "on the books", meaning that that amount would be subtracted from any further payment you are owed.  You should not fiddle with hours billed or the per-hour rate but simply hold the money as a "credit", like you'd overpaid a credit card.

Comment: It would have been slightly less confusing if he had used a comma: *go ahead and keep the difference, to be applied to the next round of work you do for us*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra amount that you received for your previous work will be subtracted from your next paycheck.

In other words, if you make $500 a week and were paid $600, expect $400 next week.

However, given that it's an issue of payment, it never hurts to clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your client would like to pay you at X USD per hour.  Since he overpaid for this he would like you to take the remaining money and apply it to the next bill.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by what "keep the difference" means.

Two of the [definitions of difference](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/difference) are:

> 1. the state or quality of being unlike
>
> 7a. the result of the subtraction of one number, quantity, etc, from another

He doesn't mean  1: expect rate Y to continue, even though it is different from X.

He means 7a: Retain possession of the extra pay, Y-X. You will be paid X - (Y-X), or 2X-Y, next time.